# strtok() not reading past the first input piece

Tags: c, shell, tokenize, strtok

I am trying to write a Linux shell replacement for an operating systems class and am having trouble parsing the input strings. I am able to read in the very first line of a string input, but once it reaches any space delimiter, it completely skips everything else and proceeds to a new prompt.  Below is the code I have for what I am trying to handle.

```
while(1){

    //Flush I/O streams to prevent duplicate '#' printing each new line
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("# ");

    //Take in the input and store it in an auxiliary variable.
    scanf("%s", input);

    strcpy(commandInput, input);

    char *ptr = strtok(commandInput, delimiter); //Parse the command and check what it is below.

    if(strcmp(commandInput, "byebye") == 0){ //End the shell program
        
        exit(1);

    } else if(strcmp(commandInput, "whereami") == 0){ //Get the current working directory

        getCurrentDirectory();
        break;

    } else if(strcmp(commandInput, "movetodir") == 0){
        
        //Store the new directory name once returned 
        strcpy(currentDirectory, changeDirectory());

        break;

    } else {
        //Handles any invalid input strings of any length

        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        while(ptr != NULL){

            printf("%s\n", ptr);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

        }
    }
}
```

As an example, below is the output I get when I input a random string that has a space between the tokens:

```
# hi there
hi
hi
# byebye
```

It should be printing out 'there' as well, but it never reaches it.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do _not_ do `fflush` on an _input_ stream--it does wacky things, so eliminate the `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: What kinds of things does that do? I would have thought it'd be good to clear both the input and output streams most of the time.

Comment: It's useless/UB for an input stream. It's only valid use is to _force_ out _buffered_ output on an output stream. At best, it does nothing. At worst, it trashes the input buffer. There are plenty of SO questions/answers that explain why. Also, see `man fflush`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned [in my top comment], do *not* do `fflush` on an *input* stream.

You are doing:

```
scanf("%s",input);
```

This will only get the *first* token on a given line. So, if the input line was (e.g.) `hello world`, the `scanf` will only put `hello` into `input`

Replace with:

```
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
```

To account for the *newline* that `fgets` leaves in the buffer, be sure that `delimiter` is something like:

```
const char *delimiter = " \t\n";
```

Comment: I hate scanf. fgets for the win.

Comment: I hate it, too. I just saw a comment today/yesterday that recommended `fgets` and suggested that `scanf` had too many side effects for a "new" programmer. It took all my [polite] restraint to _not_ add (e.g.) "or _any_ programmer" ;-) I presume it's taught in school [as a convenience/shortcut] but I've seen [way] too many SO questions where is being misused [by innocent, impressionable, young programmers :-)]

Comment: I feel like we should ship a really simple library that acts more like Basic's INPUT statement. It'd be a lot easier to use.

Comment: My first language was Fortran IV [and my second was Basic], circa 1972. My impression of `scanf` was its an attempt to mimic Fortran's `FORMAT` statement with `READ`.